# Laravel 4.2 and URLS

Tags: laravel-4, routes

I will have url that will look like the following

```
      whatever.com/products/accessories/1
      whatever.com/products/amplifiers/2
      whatever.com/products/speakers/3
```

I have read and searched everywhere but cannot figure out how I can handle this with one Route::

If I do the following

```
      whatever.com/products/1
      whatever.com/products/2
      whatever.com/products/3
```

I can use the following Route::

```
    Route::model('product', 'Product');

    Route::get('products/{product}', function(Product $product)
    {
        return View::make('product', array('product' => $product->toArray()));
    });
```

But this dos not make very friendly urls

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to enforce the middle parameter and make it meaningful, while still building off of the final ID passed, you can use [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-model-binding) with a resolver function. The second parameter passed to the resolver function is an instance of `Illuminate\Routing\Route` and if you check its [API](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html) you will see that it has a `parameter()` method that allows you to get the value of *any* parameter in the route. That allows you to have access to both parameters and build a query from it.

```
Route::bind('product', function($value, $route){
    $category = $route->parameter('category');
    $product = Product::where(['id' => $value, 'category' => $category])->first();
    return $product ?: 'Not found';
});

Route::get('products/{category}/{product}', function($category, $product)
{
    return View::make('product', array('product' => $product->toArray()));
});
```

Note that I am returning a string that says `'Not found'` if there is no result, but you could return anything. This allows you to enforce that middle parameter actually has meaning so that `whatever.com/products/amplifiers/2` will return a real result while `whatever.com/products/fake/2` will not.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching I found the following solution

Route::get('products/{p1?}/{p2?}/{p3?}/{p4?}', 'ProductController@index');

Comment: While you *could* use optional parameters like this, it still doesn't address the fact that your middle "product category" parameter is meaningless as you could type anything and it would still match. Please check my solution which would allow both of the parameters to still be enforced and have meaning.